# How can i make an overlay which can see whats on the screen?

Tags: c#, screen, overlay

I want to make an overlay which can analyse the screen and search for specific pictures on it. E.g in a game to see how much your invetory is worth or to count something in a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenCV (with python, I would almost always prefer to do such tasks with python).

But if you have to do it using C#, then you need the C# OpenCV wrapper "Emgu CV".